# Make pre-push hook changes part of pushed content to git server

Tags: git, git-bash, githooks

I have a script which executes on git pre-push hook. Inside there is PowerShell script which modifies project file in repository. This file will be properly modified localy but that change won't end up on the git server.

Here is a script:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/bin/sh.exe
branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

if [ $branch = "development" ]; 
then
    exec powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File update_version.ps1 -mode dev
pwd
fi

exit
```

Comment: I’m sure you have your reasons for enforcing this in a commit hook, but it may be simpler to move that logic into a build script instead.

Comment: This should happen only on push.

Comment: That's meaningless. pre-push hook can prevent push but cannot change existing commits on the fly. The proper way to change commit is pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 0):

As [phd said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003965/make-pre-push-hook-changes-part-of-pushed-content-to-git-server#comment87028631_50003965), you can't.<sup>1</sup>  The reason is that `git push` pushes *commits*, not files.

It's true that commits *contain* files—each commit is a complete snapshot of *all* the files that are in that commit—so `git push` winds up sending files along with the commits; but the key to this problem is that `git push` finds some set of commits, in your own Git repository, that the other Git to which you are pushing does *not* have.  Your Git packages up those commits—the author and log message, previous commit hash, snapshot of source tree, and so on—and sends them.  A pre-push hook is intended to test whether or not to send these commits.

You should (see footnote 1) write your pre-push script to *check* to make sure that the appropriate version information is in place, and if not, abort the push.  Then, *instead of* running `git push`, run `my-script-that-updates-and-then-runs-git-push`.  That script will update and commit as appropriate, then run a `git push` that succeeds despite the check, then do whatever else is appropriate if anything.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Can't" is a strong word.  You *can*, but only via [Rube Goldberg machinery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) that I would recommend avoiding.