# How to git push only files smaller than certain limit?

Tags: git

My git repository has certain max file size limit. My local repository has some big files. Is it possible to `push` only the files that do not exceed the file size limit? And if so, how to do it?

Is it necessary to make a separate commit with smaller files in order to push them or can I just use the commit that includes all the files (big and small)?

Comment: One thing to check is you've got a sufficiently strict `.gitignore` to prevent mistakes like this from happening by accident.

Comment: use `.gitignore`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035779/gitignore-by-file-size

Comment: `git push` pushes *commits*, not files. See my answer to a slightly-related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50007071/1256452

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge (assuming that you want your repository to keep track of those files). Consider using [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/), which will store your large files separately on some other server and only store references to those files in your repository (but when you check out a commit, any files it references will automatically be downloaded).

Answer (score 0):

No git flags exist for limiting the file size. The following code accomplishes what you ask:

```
find * -size -4M -type f -print | xargs git add
```

For files with spaces use `-print0` in `find`